# Java TicTacToe program triggers at non winning combinations

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I made a GUI TicTacToe game years ago and wanted to redo it since I now have more programming skills. I was able to shrink the code from 600 lines to around 150 lines.

While I used the same scheme, I ran into some problems that I couldn't solve myself, so please help me out.

The program consists of two classes, the main class `TTTMain`:

```
public class TTTMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TTTFrame tttf = new TTTFrame(0,0);
    
    /*Tic Tac Toe Field:
     *  0 1 2
     *  3 4 5
     *  6 7 8
    */
    
}}
```

And `TTTFrame`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TTTFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Button[] btnPlayButton;
    private Button btnRestart;
    private int buttonCounter;
    private int xScore;
    private int oScore;
    private Label Olabel, Xlabel;

    TTTFrame(int xScore, int oScore) {

        this.xScore = xScore;
        this.oScore = oScore;

        btnPlayButton = new Button[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            btnPlayButton[i] = new Button("" + i);
            btnPlayButton[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            btnPlayButton[i].setForeground(Color.white);
            btnPlayButton[i].addActionListener(this);
            this.add(btnPlayButton[i]);
        }

        Xlabel = new Label("X: " + this.xScore);
        Xlabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        Xlabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        Xlabel.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.add(Xlabel);

        btnRestart = new Button("Restart");
        btnRestart.setActionCommand("Restart");
        btnRestart.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        btnRestart.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnRestart);

        Olabel = new Label("O: " + this.oScore);
        Olabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        Olabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        Olabel.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.add(Olabel);

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        this.setSize(300, 400);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Restart")) {
            System.out.println("Restarted");
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

                btnPlayButton[i].setLabel("" + i);
                btnPlayButton[i].setForeground(Color.white);
                btnPlayButton[i].setBackground(Color.white);
                btnPlayButton[i].addActionListener(this);

                this.buttonCounter = 0;
            }
        } else {

            ((Button) e.getSource()).setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48));
            ((Button) e.getSource()).setForeground(Color.black);
            System.out.println(buttonCounter);
            if (buttonCounter % 2 == 0) {
                ((Button) e.getSource()).setLabel("X");
                ((Button) e.getSource()).removeActionListener(this);
            } else {
                ((Button) e.getSource()).setLabel("O");
                ((Button) e.getSource()).removeActionListener(this);
            }
            buttonCounter++;
            CheckField();
        }

    }

    private void CheckField() {

        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(0, 1, 2)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(3, 4, 5)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(6, 7, 8)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(0, 3, 6)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(1, 4, 7)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(2, 5, 8)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(0, 4, 8)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
        if (ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(2, 4, 6)) {

            Deactivatebuttons();
        }
    }

    private boolean ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(int i, int j, int k) {
        if (btnPlayButton[i].getLabel() == btnPlayButton[j].getLabel()
                && btnPlayButton[j].getLabel() == btnPlayButton[k].getLabel()) {
    
            btnPlayButton[i].setBackground(Color.red);
            btnPlayButton[j].setBackground(Color.red);
            btnPlayButton[k].setBackground(Color.red);

            if (btnPlayButton[i].getLabel().equals("X")) {
                xScore++;
                Xlabel.setText("X: " + xScore);
            } else {
                oScore++;
                Olabel.setText("O: " + oScore);
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void Deactivatebuttons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            btnPlayButton[i].removeActionListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now let me explain how the program works. The 3x3 playing field is made of the ButtonArray `btnPlayButton`. The buttons are **compared by their Labels**, so to not have matching labels at the start of the game the buttons are labeled from 1 to 9 right when they are created. Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        btnPlayButton[i] = new Button("" + i); // Right here
        btnPlayButton[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        btnPlayButton[i].setForeground(Color.white);
        btnPlayButton[i].addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnPlayButton[i]);
    }
```

Whenever you click a `btnPlayButton` , the program jumps into the `actionPerformed` method. Since the `btnPlayButtons` don't have an `ActionCommand` , it jumps right into the else section of the method. Here, int `buttonCounter` gets greater by 1. Wether `buttonCounter` is even or odd, the btnPlayButton that got clicked gets relabeled with "X" or "O". Since `buttonCounter` gets +1 with every click, the X and Os are alternating.

Here is said section:

```
else {

    ((Button) e.getSource()).setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48));
    ((Button) e.getSource()).setForeground(Color.black);
    System.out.println(buttonCounter);
    if (buttonCounter % 2 == 0) {
        ((Button) e.getSource()).setLabel("X");
        ((Button) e.getSource()).removeActionListener(this);
    } else {
        ((Button) e.getSource()).setLabel("O");
        ((Button) e.getSource()).removeActionListener(this);
    }
    buttonCounter++;
    CheckField();
}
```

The `ActionListener` of the clicked Button are removed to prevent cheating. With every buttonpress, the playing field is checked for a winning combination. This happens in `CheckField()`.

In `CheckField()`, or to be more precisely, `ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels(x, y, z)` the labels of `btnPlayButtons[x]`, `btnPlayButtons[y]`, `btnPlayButtons[z]` are taken and compared, if they are identical it returns true.

Since the btnPlayButton are ordered like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

the winning combinations are: 012,345,678,036,147,258,045 and 246

so, for example, when `btnPlayButton[0]`, `btnPlayButton[1]` and `btnPlayButton[2]` all have the same label. `ButtonsWithIdenticalLabels` is true and the program jumps into `Deactivatebuttons()` where all the `btnPlayButton` are getting disabled meaning a winning combination was found and the game is over. If the label of `btnPlayButton[1]` is "X" then `int xScore` gets 1 added to it. Also `btnPlayButton[0]`, `btnPlayButton[1]` and `btnPlayButton[2]` get painted red for aesthetics.

With the Restart button you jump into a for loop that relabels the btnPlayButton again and adds them the `ActionListener` that is implemented into TTTFrame. `buttonCounter` is getting resetted to 0 as well. The relabeling is the same as the one in the beginning of the class:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Restart")) {
            System.out.println("Restarted");
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

                btnPlayButton[i].setLabel("" + i);
                btnPlayButton[i].setForeground(Color.white);
                btnPlayButton[i].setBackground(Color.white);
                btnPlayButton[i].addActionListener(this);

                this.buttonCounter = 0;
            }
```

Now the problem is that I have is, that after a few restarts, the labeling of X and O isn't alternating anymore. Sometimes there are 3 Os in a row and sometimes even Fields like this are getting recognized as a win

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w6TO.png)

If someone knows how to fix this bug I'd be really happy.

Thanks in advance,

Fihdi

Comment: With this much code in the question you are not so likely to get help here. Have you tried to debug it yourself already? That should help you to locate the bug and come back with a more specific question here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Please read (and follow) the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The main problem here is that your whole game is contained within one class. Do a refactor and probably you will be able to find the problem. If you continue to develop in the same fashion you are going to have more problems, which will be harder to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is: When you restart the game, a new `ActionListener` is added to every button. However, it's only removed when you either click it or when someone wins the game. That means when you restart a game before anyone won, every non-clicked button gets a second `ActionListener`, so the click will be registered twice and this bug appears. Try to call `DeactivateButtons()` before you reset the board.